# как создать соединение по websocket со стороны сервера в Delphi XE8?

Tags: delphi, websocket

как создать соединение по websocket со стороны сервера?

есть какой то компонент специальный, в инди например?

Comment: 1. [DelphiWebsockets](https://github.com/andremussche/DelphiWebsockets) (opensource); 2. [IP*Works! WS](https://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/ws/#plat-delphi) (платный); 3. Есть ещё 100500 библиотек - гугл в помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://websockets.esegece.com/

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  ... sgcWebSocket_Classes, sgcWebSocket_Server, sgcWebSocket;
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    sgcWebSocketServer1: TsgcWebSocketServer;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure sgcWebSocketServer1Message(Connection: TsgcWSConnection;
      const Text: string);
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  cguid: String;    
implementation    
{$R *.dfm}    
procedure TForm1.sgcWebSocketServer1Message(Connection: TsgcWSConnection;
  const Text: string);
begin
  cguid := Conection.Guid;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Text); // запрос    
  Connection.WriteData('Ответ');
end;

end.
```

или

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sgcWebSocketServer1.WriteData(cguid, 'message');
end;
```

Comment: Все хорошо, только добавлю, что библиотека стоит 200 евро.